# How to change scroll bar margin in QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I need that scroll bar in QListWidget have

```
margin = 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a stylesheet, for example look at this :

```
QScrollBar:horizontal {
    background: transparent;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

QScrollBar:vertical {
    background: transparent;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background: #374146;
    min-width: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background: #374146;
    min-height: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal,
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal,
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
      border: none;
      background: none;
}

QListWidget QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
        background-color:rgb(0, 170, 171);
}
QListWidget QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
        background-color:rgb(0, 170, 171);
        margin:2;
}
```

**output**

[image]

I set margin 2, margin 6 looks like this

[image]